# Error when trying to play a wav file from server to client browser

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to load and play a `wav` file using:

```
Dim MyPlayer As New SoundPlayer()
MyPlayer.SoundLocation = "http://api.smartercall.in/storage/" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("FileName").ToString()
MyPlayer.Play()
```

I get a following error after hosting this code

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer.ValidateSoundData(Byte[] data)
at System.Media.SoundPlayer.LoadAndPlay(Int32 flags)
at SmartCall.staff_campaign.btnplay_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: The code you try to run from client is on server side. This is not the way to work on Internet and browsers, this is the way for desktop programming, not for internet. The `Play` Call, is run on server, not on your client browser.

Comment: then what is the code for running on server?

Comment: refer [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1254313.aspx?How+to+play+wav+file+in+asp+net+) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/618151/how-to-play-a-wav-file-in-asp-net)

Comment: still its not working

Comment: Well the update your question or create a new one with a title such as `Error when trying to play wav file on client`

Comment: please anybody help to clear the error